# How do I extract contents between two line starting and ending with same strings in perl?

Tags: perl

The data file contains the following content

```
 7e a1 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 05 00 00 00
 ea 5b ee fb 7e 7e a1 01  00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 05 00 00 00 c0 9c ba e1  66 7e 7e a1 02 00 00
 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00  00 c0 47 9f 80 1a 7e
```

When I try to print between linest from 1st `7e` to 2nd `7e` and consecutively from 3rd `7e` to 4th `7e` in which my expected output is as below excluding quoted `'7e'` in each line since start and end are same the conventional method is not working.

```
 `7e` a1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 ea 5b ee fb `7e` 
 `7e` a1 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 c0 9c ba e1 66 `7e`
 `7e` a1 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 c0 47 9f 80 1a `7e`
```

I have tried with the following initial perl but results are not as expected, can anyone clarify my understanding, I have tried the following,

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    my $filename = 'input_file.txt';
    open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
      or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
    my $count=0;
    while (<$fh>) {
      if (/7e/../7e/) {
        next if /7e/ || /7e/;
        print;
      }
    }
```

also need to check at each even ending of `7e` ie 2nd,4th etc.. the next starting should be `7e` or else should flag an error.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a hex dump, which would make `7e` represent `~`. Are you sure that parsing the hex dump is what you want to do?

The problem with your code is that your data spans over line endings, and you are reading the file in line-by-line mode. Moreover, you are skipping lines which contain `7e`, which would mean that you cut content from some lines.

This would probably be simplest to solve by using the record input separator, and set it to `7e`. This indicates that you are reading lines which end with the string `7e`, instead of `\n`.

I am also using a counter to skip the odd lines. I am using `Data::Dumper` to display the data in a more readable way.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

$/ = '7e';
my $count;
my @data;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if ($count++ % 2) {
        push @data, $_;
    } else {
        warn "Data in wrong place ('$_')" if /\S/;
    }
}
print Dumper \@data;

__DATA__
 7e a1 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 05 00 00 00
 ea 5b ee fb 7e 7e a1 01  00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 05 00 00 00 c0 9c ba e1  66 7e 7e a1 02 00 00
 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00  00 c0 47 9f 80 1a 7e
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          ' a1 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 05 00 00 00
 ea 5b ee fb ',
          ' a1 01  00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 05 00 00 00 c0 9c ba e1  66 ',
          ' a1 02 00 00
 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00  00 c0 47 9f 80 1a '
        ];
```

Comment: Yes this works fine and I could parse data between `7e`'s but the tedious part here is after the 2nd, 4th,. `7e` the immediate byte should also start with `7e` or else an error has to be triggered..that is were I am stuck still.. is there a way for it..

Comment: Yes, instead of `next` you use your own method to check what is between the even delimiters. Probably check for anything not whitespace, e.g. `warn "Data in the wrong place" if /\S/`.

Comment: I think I need to detail it further..here after the end of the first delimiter `7e` the second should start with `7e` considering this eg: 7e a1 00 `7e` a1 00 here in this case it should trigger an error message since after the 2nd `7e` the byte immediate to it does not start with `7e`

Comment: Yes, including a test case which also demonstrates the error condition would be a good idea. The above should work. That will be 50 euro.

Answer (score 1):

A large part of your problem is that the data is split across lines. You really need to process each byte separately

This process reads in the entire dump and puts all the data into a single line in `$data` with a single space between the bytes. Then a simple global regex pattern finds all the subsequences that you want

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

local $/;
my $data = join ' ', split ' ', <DATA>;

say $1 while $data =~ /7e\s(.+?)\s7e/g;

__DATA__
 7e a1 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 05 00 00 00
 ea 5b ee fb 7e 7e a1 01  00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 05 00 00 00 c0 9c ba e1  66 7e 7e a1 02 00 00
 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00  00 c0 47 9f 80 1a 7e
```

#### output

```
a1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 ea 5b ee fb
a1 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 c0 9c ba e1 66
a1 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 c0 47 9f 80 1a
```

Comment: Yes you are right byte operation needed,here after 2nd,4th,6th,8th ... `7e` the immediate byte should also start with `7e` or an error has to be triggered is there any solution for this.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking—what is *the immediate byte*?—but it's a different question anyway and should be posted as such

Comment: I have already mentioned in the question, if you can read the last 2 lines of the question it says that at each start and end of `7e` the next starting string or byte should be `7e` or else an error should be triggered. eg: 7e a1 00 `7e` a1 01 ... here an error should be triggered since after 2nd `7e` the immediate or following sequence did not start with expected `7e`.